# XSL use variable to get attribute

Tags: xslt

I have a code to output options list:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="option">
    <xsl:param name="value" select="'value'"/>
    <option>
        <xsl:attribute name="value" select="./@($value)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@name"/>
    </option>
</xsl:template>
```

The question is how can i get an attribute value which name is in variable $value?
What should i use instead of not working construction: ./@($value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a parameter or variable value then `$value` is all you need, i.e. `<xsl:attribute name="value" select="$value"/>` to create an attribute with name `value` and with the value of the parameter which is also `value`. If you want to read out the value of an attribute named like your parameter then you would use `<xsl:attribute name="value" select="@*[local-name() eq $value]"/>`.

You could also consider an attribute value template for brevity:

```
<option value="{$value}"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></option>
```

respectively

```
<option value="{@*[local-name() eq $value]}"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></option>
```

Comment: NB if this is XSLT 1.0 then you need to use `=` instead of `eq`.

Comment: @IanRoberts, the use of `xsl:attribute name="value" select` made me assume XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Good point.  I forget sometimes exactly which features belong to which versions.